# Как запретить нажимать на кнопку

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css3

Мне нужно запретить нажимать на кнопку, пока он не нажмёт на checkbox, как реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let checkBox = document.querySelector('#checkbox');
let button = document.querySelector('#button');
checkBox.addEventListener('change', () => {
  button.disabled = !button.disabled;
})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<input type="button" id="button" disabled value="Отправить">
```

Answer (score 2):

Вешаем событие `click` на кнопку. При событии проверяем отметки на `checkbox`

```js
$(function() {
  $('form button').click(function(e) {
    if (!$('form>input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked')) {
      alert('Нужно отметить checkbox!');
      return false;
    }
    alert('OK');
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="test">
    <button>button</button>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<form class="form">
  <input type="checkbox" class="check">
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Кнопка</button>
</form>
```

```
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var i = document.querySelector(".check");
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(i.checked){
    alert("Победа");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Если кнопка следует за чекбоксом на одном уровне вложенности:

```css
:not(:checked) + #button{
  pointer-events:none;
  color:gray;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<input type="button" id="button" value="Отправить" onclick="console.log('click')">
```

В остальных случаях - `JS`